# HTML thead border is partially shown on previous page when printing with Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, puppeteer

As stated, the issue is that part of the border is shown on the previous page. Have also been seeing the same behaviour with backgrounds.

**Code** (doesn't work when printed from snippet so included as text)**:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <style>
    thead {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }

    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Issue with Chrome print:**
[image]

Comment: Don't know if it was implied, but is it working correctly in other browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `border` overlaps the `<table>` and is outside of the table. So your document starts with the `border` of `<thead>` followed by the `<table>`. You can use a `box-shadow` (with `inset`) to get a inner border.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    thead {
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
    }
    thead th {
      padding: 2px 2px;
    }
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

... or a `transform: translateY(2px);` on the `<table>` (`margin` doesn't work too):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    thead {
      border:2px solid red;
    }
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      transform: translateY(2px);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr> <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr> <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td><td>D3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```